# Convert External HDD via USB as Removable Disk

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have an external HDD (500GB) that I took from a laptop and put it into a casing as an external HDD with USB 3.

And also I have a car which can use a USB flashdisk as a media source such as movies and music.

The external HDD I would like to plug into the car but the car only accepting removable disk as media source and no matter what format (NTFS, FAT32, ExFAT) I put into the car it's still not recognized as a media source.

Is there a trick to make the external HDD as a removable disk so I can have the external HDD as media source for my car?

- External HDD in PC is showing as LOCAL DISK, I figure if I could convert it to as removable disk, the car would think it's a removable flash disk.

Answer (score 0):

The casing houses a controller. This controller determines to the connected source what kind of device is connected. In this case, it seems the controller seems to transmit as a harddisk rather than a removable drive.

Do note, I think the reason your car stereo is not able to read the drive is not due to the controller, but due to the filesize. Check the manual with the car stereo to find out how big the usb drive can be for it to still be recognized. The limit is probably 16gb, 32gb, 64gb or 128gb, depending on the age of the stereo.

You could try creating a partition with this maximum on the harddisk and see if it gets recognized.